# Finding Brackets in Java Regex String

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I am trying to put all the different types of brackets i.e `(, {, and [`, in a given string into an array using Regex, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my current code :

```
String s = "{[()]}";
String regexStr = "\\( | \\) | \\[ | \\] | \\{ | \\}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
String[] splitStr = p.split(s);
```

When I print the array though, there is only one element which is the original string: `"{[()]}"`. I'm not sure if my regexStr is right, I added spaces next to the OR because when I didn't leave spaces, there was nothing being added to the array.

The regexStr works in the online Java regex checker I use when I don't have spaces, but it doesn't seem to work in my code.

Comment: Can you show some sample output?

Comment: You can't use `split` for this. The pattern on which `split` is called is the _boundary_, and will actually be removed from the split result. I would go with the answer from @brso05 below

Comment: @jingx in fact you can you just need to make some operation before you can check my answer above :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "{[()]}";
    String regexStr = "[\\{|\\}|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        temp.add(m.group());
    }
    //If you want to add results to an array...
    String[] results = new String[temp.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        results[i] = temp.get(i);
    }
    for(String a : results)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: note you have to make some changes in your code 1- you can just use `List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();` 2- when you use characters between `[]` you don't need to use the or `|` so instead you can just use `"[\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]]"`  3- to print  your list you can just use `System.out.println(temp);` fix it and your solution will be perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just use `"{[()]}".split("")` for example :

```
String[] spl = "{[()]}".split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
```

**Output**

```
[{, [, (, ), ], }]
```

---

**Solution 2**

If your input contain other characters then you can replace them first and use the previouse solution for example :

```
String s = "{[(hello)java]world}";
String[] spl = s.replaceAll("[^\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]]", "").split("");
```

## regex demo

Comment: yes @brso05 probably, can you check my solution now

Comment: Well, granted technically this works, but I don't see any advantages doing it this way. In fact, now IMHO the best answer is the one below that simply loops through  the string and looks for individual bracket characters. It's more efficient than the regex-based solutions, and actually much easier to read.

Comment: @jingx the OP ask for regex, so we answer with regex thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try converting a string to char array then iterate through that array and if a particular bracket exists, use an arraylist to append

```
string="Hello)"
char[] a= string.toCharArray();
ArrayList brackets= new ArrayList()<>
for(char i : a)
{
if(i==')' || any other bracket)
{
brackets.add(i);
}
}
```